# why I am getting this error "no instance of constructor", viennacl library in a CUDA optimizer, C++ console app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, viennacl

I am trying to run this C++ console app project using cmakefile and I am getting this error for a cuda optimizer which was written in this project.

```
// wrap the existing CUDA CSR data in a viennacl::compressed_matrix:
    viennacl::compressed_matrix<double> vcl_A(d_L_Row, d_L_Col, d_L, viennacl::CUDA_MEMORY, ncols, ncols, nnzL);
    viennacl::vector<double> vcl_R(d_R, viennacl::CUDA_MEMORY, ncols);
    viennacl::vector<double> vcl_X(X, viennacl::CUDA_MEMORY, ncols);
```

for above part of code shows this error:

> no instance of constructor "viennacl::compressed_matrix<NumericT, AlignmentV>::compressed_matrix [with NumericT=double, AlignmentV=1U]" matches the argument list

what exactly this means? how to fix it?

Comment: Not familiar with the viennaci library but what constructor are you trying to use for `vlc_A`? I don't see any matching in the [documentation](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/doc/classviennacl_1_1compressed__matrix.html) (I found this googling around, not sure if it's up to date)

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that your line

```
viennacl::compressed_matrix<double> vcl_A(d_L_Row, d_L_Col, d_L, viennacl::CUDA_MEMORY, ncols, ncols, nnzL)
```

does not match the expected signature. In this particular case the constructor is defined as

```
explicit compressed_matrix(unsigned int *mem_row_buffer,
                           unsigned int *mem_col_buffer,
                           NumericT *mem_elements,       // NumericT is double as per template argument
                           viennacl::memory_types mem_type,                              
                           vcl_size_t rows,  // size_t
                           vcl_size_t cols,  // size_t 
                           vcl_size_t nonzeros) // size_t
```

Since integer conversion to vcl_size_t is unlikely to cause this error, most likely the pointer types do not match. Make sure `d_L_Row` and `d_L_Col` are pointers to `unsigned int` and `d_L` is a pointer to `double`. Your compiler has probably provided additional hints as to why the matching fails.

Since you are using CUDA, also make sure that the preprocessor define `VIENNACL_WITH_CUDA` is set before the respective `#include` statements for the ViennaCL headers.

Comment: Everything in the original code as you said. Pointer types are exactly same as you mentioned.